# Proving complex function is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

[image: So this is my problem], I get that from the restrictions on $a,b$ we get that they can't both be $0$. I tried taking the partial with respect to $x$ of the given constant function but could not translate that into a 0 for the derivative of f or even a 0 for the partial of $Im(f)$ or $Re(f)$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a = 0$ (resp. $b = 0$), then $\textrm{Re}(f(z))$ is constant (resp. $\textrm{Im}(f(z))$ is constant), in which case it's easy to show that $f$ must be constant using the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

If $a,b \neq 0$, then
$$\textrm{Im}(f(z)) = \frac{1}{b}(c - a\textrm{Re}(f(z))$$
for some constant $c$. Again the Cauchy-Riemann equations will show you that $f$ must be constant.

Comment: How come $a,b \neq0\implies Re(f(z))=cIm(f(z))$?

Comment: Thanks I was able to work it out using this, not sure why I did not simply plug into the CR equations!

Comment: CR equations are usually the way to go for those "real and imaginary parts satisfy x, show the function is constant" problems.

Answer (score 0):

Define $c = a - ib$ and $g(z) = c f(z)$. Then
$$
\operatorname{Re}g(z) = a \operatorname{Re}f(z) + b \operatorname{Im}f(z)
$$
is constant. Apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations to $g$ to conclude
that $g$  is constant. Since $c \ne 0$,  $f = g/c$ is constant as well.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f=u+iv.$ Consider $g(z)= e^{(a-ib)f(z)}.$ Then $|g(z)| = e^{au(z) + bv(z)},$ which from the given hypothesis is constant. By the open mapping theorem, $g$ is constant. That implies $(a-ib)f(z)$ is constant, which implies $f$ is constant.